# How can you reduced using repeated code in this JavaScript function? Checking for all checked inputs in different divs using Event Listener

Tags: javascript

In the function validateDemographics() two arrays are being stored and updated based on if they are checked or unchecked in their respect divs. \I have tried to separate the concern here to have each main div's logic in separate functions. One function for Borrower and the other function for CoBorrower. This will work but the code will still be duplicated in some areas. Is there a clean way to reduce the code and have one function that either passes some values? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
function validateDemographics() {
// Use Array.forEach to add an event listener to each checkbox.
checkBorrowerBoxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
        enabledBorrowerCheckbox =
            Array.from(checkBorrowerBoxes)
                .filter(i => i.checked)
                .map(i => i.value)

        hideOrShowNextBtn();
    })
});

checkCoBorrowerBoxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
        enabledCoBorrowerCheckbox =
            Array.from(checkCoBorrowerBoxes)
                .filter(i => i.checked)
                .map(i => i.value)

        hideOrShowNextBtn();
    })
});
}



function hideOrShowNextBtn() {
if (enabledBorrowerCheckbox.length > 0 && enabledCoBorrowerCheckbox.length > 0) {
    nextBtn.classList.remove("hide");
} else {
    nextBtn.classList.add('hide');
 }
}
```

Comment: create a function, like `const fn = arg => Array.from(arg).filter(i => i.checked).map(i => i.value);` - then you can do `enabledBorrowerCheckbox = fn(checkBorrowerBoxes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function do perform the "repeated" task

e.g.

```
const fn = arg => Array.from(arg).filter(i => i.checked).map(i => i.value);
```

Then your code will be

```
function validateDemographics() {
    const fn = arg => Array.from(arg).filter(i => i.checked).map(i => i.value);
    // Use Array.forEach to add an event listener to each checkbox.
    checkBorrowerBoxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            enabledBorrowerCheckbox = fn(checkBorrowerBoxes);
            enabledCoBorrowerCheckbox = fn(checkCoBorrowerBoxes);
            hideOrShowNextBtn();
        });
    });

    checkCoBorrowerBoxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            enabledCoBorrowerCheckbox = fn(checkCoBorrowerBoxes);
            hideOrShowNextBtn();
        })
    });
}
```

Note: you could also do

```
const fn = arg => Array.from(arg, i => i.value).filter(i => i.checked);
```

it uses the optional `map` callback for `Array.from` - for even shorter code if that's important to you

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for the suggestion. Condenses the code way more.

Comment: @IsiahJones - added an option for slightly (like 6 bytes maybe, didn't count) shorter code :p